# Change image to be loaded based on switch status

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I am using AngularJS material. I would like to load an image based on the switch status. Below is the relevant HTML code.

If `sw_status.sw1 == true`, load image `truePic.jpg`. If `sw_status.sw1 == false`, load image `falsePic.jpg`.

```
<div ng-controller="AGCtrl">
    <md-switch ng-model="sw_status.sw1" aria-label="Switch_1" ng-change="onChange(sw_status.sw1)">
        Switch_1: {{ sw_status.sw1 }}
    </md-switch>
</div>
<img src='img/truePic.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img ng-src="{{sw_status.sw1 ? 'truePic.jpg' : 'falsePic.jpg'}}">
```